# How is cdf input converted from negative to positive?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose X has normal $(μ,σ^{2})$ distribution, and $P(X \leq 0)=1/3, P(X \leq 1)=2/3$

What are the values of μ and σ?

$\frac{1}{3}=P(X \leq 0)=P(\frac{X-μ}{σ} \leq \frac{0-μ}{σ})=φ(\frac{-μ}{σ})$

$φ(\frac{-μ}{σ})=\frac{1}{3} → φ(\frac{μ}{σ})=\frac{2}{3} → \frac{μ}{σ}=φ^{-1}(\frac{2}{3})=0.43$

I don't understand how this $φ(\frac{-μ}{σ})=\frac{1}{3} → φ(\frac{μ}{σ})=\frac{2}{3}$ happened.

Comment: Are you talking about a specific distribution?

Comment: Specific to the given example. I think I'll get how it's done generally if I understand this example. If I don't, I'll ask more questions.

Comment: What you have written is not true in general but it could be true for a particular distribution. Also $\mu$ should be negative since CDF is non-decreasing so $\mu/\sigma=0.43$ is simply not true if $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

Comment: Ok, I added some more details. Can you check if it makes sense now?

Comment: In the first line you say $\psi(-\mu/\sigma)=1/3$, in the next you say $\psi(-\mu/\sigma)=1/2$?

Comment: Sorry, there were some massive typos in my first post. They're fixed now. It's $1/3$ to $2/3$ And first and second line match now.

Comment: You can't infer $\Phi(\mu/\sigma)=2/3$ from the given information. It is not true in general.

Comment: But that's what the textbook solution says... If I try $Φ(1.22) - Φ(0.14) = 0.3333 = 1/3$, then it's $μ/σ = 1.08$, which is not the given solution $0.43$.

Comment: You will have to provide more details about the distribution.

Comment: Ok, I added the full question. I think I understand where I went wrong with my original post. I forgot to add that $P(X \leq 1)=2/3$. But I still don't understand how it is so.

Comment: It all gets sorted now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make use of a special property of the CDF of standard normal distributions, namely $\Phi(x)+\Phi(-x)=1\forall x\in\Bbb R$. It is easy to see why this is true:$$\begin{align*}\Phi(x)+\Phi(-x)&=\int_{-\infty}^x f(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^{-x}f(x)dx\\&=-\int_{-\infty}^x f(-(-x))d(-x)+\int_{-\infty}^{-x}f(x)dx\\&=-\int_\infty^{-x} f(-y)dy+\int_{-\infty}^{-x}f(x)dx\end{align*}$$ where $y=-x$ and $f(x)$ is the PDF of standard normal distribution. $f(x)$ is even so $f(-y)=f(y)$, giving$$\int^\infty_{-x} f(y)dy+\int_{-\infty}^{-x}f(x)dx=1$$You can extend this concept to general normal distributions:$$F(\mu-x)+F(\mu+x)=1$$

Comment: Here's what I'm confused about. So for $P(X \leq 1)=2/3$, it says $φ([1-μ]/σ)=2/3$. How can both $φ(μ/σ)$ and $φ([1-μ]/σ)$ equal $2/3$?

Comment: Because $\mu/\sigma=(1-\mu)/\sigma$ ($\Phi$ is bijective).

Comment: Oh... Thank you so much! The professor skipped the CDF part and want us to learn Normal Distribution without going through it, so I was so confused. Now I get it.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: Hey, just a last bit. Can you give me a link where it shows the bijection of Φ, so that this solution works? I'm trying to look it up so I can find something solid to write down in my notes, but I'm having a hard time.

Comment: @JacobToho Can you prove that $\Phi$ is strictly increasing? The derivative of $\Phi$ is the PDF of $Z$ and the PDF is positive. Strictly increasing means that $\Phi$ is injective, which means it is bijective over its range $(0,1)$ (although we only need injectivity here)